# what is the usage of static object instantiate in java?

Tags: java, object

I have  instantiated static object in java like

```
static A1 a =new A1();
```

What is the usage of this type of declaration?
what will happen with this type of instantiated ?

Comment: please give a bit more info here. a little vague

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I want to know purpose of normal static object instantiate.

Comment: read... just try to read. plenty of resources are out there.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `a` will be an static variable of the containing class. If you have, for instance:

```
class B{
  static A1 a = new A1();
}
```

The you'll have an static variable `a` that you can access from an static scope:

```
B.a.method();
```

Comment: For Inner classes above one is correct. But i want to know purpose of normal static object instantiate.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to access it without having to instantiate B. So, you'll have a 'global' variable.